# How to check if an email address is already in use in Firebase on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using the Firebase Authentication for my iOS App. Now I want to check that the entered email address is available or not. I have found that I have to use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` for this. But the issue is I don't want to pass Password. I only want to check using Email. How can I do this?

Comment: Firebase Auth already returns an error if the email is taken. Why do you want to check before a user enters their password?

Comment: What do you mean by you want to check Email? Did you want to make sure that the Email is already used? Or what?

Comment: Actually my design is like there is first page where user will enter the email address. If that email is already registered then user navigate to next page that is password page where user will enter password and sing in into the app. So on first page i want to check that email is registered or not. @JenPerson

Comment: @JenPerson In my UI, I hide the "Sign Up" button until all fields are correctly filled in, including a *valid* email address that is not already in the database, a username that's not already been used and a passwordConfirmation field that contains the same password as the password field. This might be why he wants to check *before* issuing a createUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use fetchProvidersForEmail:completion:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-fetchprovidersforemailcompletion

It will return the list of provider IDs associated with that email. If you get 'password' in the list then an email/password account already exists for that email, you can show your sign-in page.

Answer (score 9):

The following is the structure of the [Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(im)fetchProvidersForEmail:completion:) you might be looking for (Swift 4):

```
Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: emailAddress, completion: {
        (providers, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let providers = providers {
            print(providers)
        }
    })
```

If the email address is already registered to a user, you will get a list of the providers that the email address is used for. Otherwise, the list of providers will be empty, and thus the email address is not registered.

Comment: fetchProviders is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Any user account in Firebase Authentication that has an email address can be verified, it doesn't have to be an email+password account. [To verify the email address for a user call `user.sendEmailVerification()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email).

If you want to check whether an email address is already in use before registering the user, the Firebase Admin SDK has a method to [look up a user by their email address](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data): `admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)`. This method requires administrative privileges and (like all of the Admin SDK) should only be run in a trusted environment - typically a server you control or Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Final note: be aware that even if you check if the email address is available before registering, the email address might be claimed by another user by the time you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. So as Jen commented: you will also need to handle the error that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` raises if the email address is already in use.

Comment: Thanks! Any other option without using `admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)`?

Answer (score 1):

the following code is used for the swift5 with updated firebase version. `Auth.auth().fetchSignInMethods(forEmail: emailAddress, completion: { (providers, error) in if let error = error { print(error.localizedDescription) } else if let providers = providers { print(providers) } })`

Comment: fetchSignInMethods is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this with Firebase. An email account also requires a password.

If you don't want users to have to enter a password, you could use another account option, such as Facebook, Google, Twitter etc.

Comment: Actually my design is like there is first page where user will enter the email address. If that email is already registered then user navigate to next page that is password page where user will enter password and sing in into the app. @bradley

Answer (score 0):

you just need to a create a reference while a user sign up in Parent "users" of your firebaseDB which have Email id registered as "email" with firebase app and run the following query call while you are checking for email exist or not

```
 let databaseReff = Database.database().reference().child("users")

                    databaseReff.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: self.emailTextField.text!).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
                        if snapshot.exists(){

                           //User email exist
                        }
                        else{
                            //email does not [email id available]
                        }

                    })
```